# Manipulate the special character '\' in a JAVA string

Tags: java, string, special-characters

I have this String :

```
pathfileshtml.get(b) = C:\Users\Netrill\workspace\find and fix\JAS_DOC\JAS\PRD_15M\JAS_JAE\JAS_JAE\JAS_JAE_0.1.html
```

I used this :

```
String cartella = pathfileshtml.get(b).substring(0,pathfileshtml.get(b).lastIndexOf("/"));
```

the `Exception` is `String index of range -1` in SO Windows, but it' s ok on MAC. I need now the Windows  version . How i can manipulate the character '\' in a JAVA  string on Windows? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the wrongs the special charapter is "/"

Answer (score 0):

The `\` character is called an escape character.

It is used for adding characters such as `\n` and `\b`.

If you want to use `\` you must type `\\` to have it escape itself.

Comment: The charapter is '\' and not '/' .Sorry for the title.

Comment: How must i post the sintax? String cartella = pathfileshtml.get(b).substring(0, pathfileshtml.get(b).lastIndexOf("\/")); it' s a compilation error.

Comment: If you want `/`, just leave it at `/`. If you want a `\`, you need to put a `\\`. To format your code correctly encase it with two ` signs

Comment: Because Windows path name seperators are not `/`

Comment: so how do I get what I want?

Comment: Check the operating system, if it is Windows, use \\. Else use /.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are taking the wrong approach to this.

Assuming that you are on a Windows machine trying to manipulate a Windows pathname, you should be doing something like this to parse the pathname string as a `Path` object:

```
 Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(pathString);
```

Once you have the `Path` you can perform a variety of operations.  For instance, to get the last name in the path:

```
 String filename = path.getFileName();
```

Using the `Path` class avoids the need to parse the pathname yourself, and it (largely) insulates you from platform specific pathname syntax issues.  (The code above should work on Mac OSX, UNIX, Linux and so on ... as well as Windows.)

Comment: I' dont' t need the name of file, I need the path of last directory.